# How can I write UnitTest for service method with REQUIRES_NEW and constraint in DB

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, testing, junit, junit4

How can I create UnitTest for this method?

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Override
    public Charge saveInNewTransaction(Charge charge) {
        if (charge.getIsDuplicate()) {
            charge.setIsActive(false);
        } else {
            Charge chargeOrigin = charge.getChargeOrigin();
            chargeOrigin.setIsActive(false);
            chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(chargeOrigin);
        }

        return chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(charge);
    }
```

I have constraint - only one can be `isActive = true`

I have no idea how to write a test for this method.

brief background. I get a list of charges for example 10 and in a cycle I try to save them. if i get an constraint exception - I need ignore it(and continue save another charges. I do not need rolback main transaction).

therefore I have such a method which is executed in `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction.

EDIT

I trying:

```
@MockBean
private ChargeRepository chargeRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    chargeService = new ChargeServiceImpl(chargeRepository);
}

@Test
public void saveInNewTransaction() {

    Charge charge = new Charge();
    charge.setIsDuplicate(true);

    Charge originCharge = new Charge();
    originCharge.setIsDuplicate(false);

    charge.setChargeOrigin(originCharge);

    //when(???).thenReturn(???);

    Charge savedCharge = chargeService.saveInNewTransaction(testCharge);

     //assertThat(???);
}
```

Comment: @Patrick I eddit question

Comment: I dont think you need to test your `saveInNewTransaction` method. You want to test the method where your iteration is, right?

Comment: I need to check the constraint. I must be sure that if both charges are active I will get an exception

Comment: so its more an integration test and you will test a functionality of the database not of your code. I would not do it. But if you still want to test is, create an integration test, execute it as spring test, autowire youe repository and save the data in the way you expect the exception.